# Proof that $B[a,b]$ (bounded functions on interval) is nonseparable

Tags: general-topology, functional-analysis

> Let $B = B[a,b]$ be the set of bounded functions on the interval $[a,b]$, where $a \lt b$ are real numbers.  Then $B$ is nonseparable.

I start with assuming that $B = B[a,b]$ is separable.  Then $B$ has a subset $M$ such that $\bar M = B$.

Where: $\bar M = M  \cup \text{acc}(M)$ and $\text{acc(M)}$ is the set of accumulation points of $M$.

So $\forall f, f \in \bar M \iff f \in B$

Let $f \in B$ such that $f$ is not in $M$, then $f$ must be in $\text{acc}(M)$.

So for every open ball $b(f,r)$ there's a point $f'$ in $b$ such that $f' \in M$.

I'm trying to find a contradiction past this point but I'm having difficulty.  Anyone have any ideas?

Answer (score 3):

For each $p\in[a,b]$ define $$f_p(x) = \begin{cases}1 \quad \text{if}\quad x=p, \\ 0 \quad \text{otherwise.}\end{cases}$$
Then, $\|f_p-f_q\|=1$ for $p \neq q$, thus we have an uncountable family of vectors in $B[a,b]$ with pairwise distances of $1$.

Now, a dense subset $S \subset B[a,b]$ should have an element $s_p \in S$ such that $\|s_p-f_p\| \leq \frac{1}{3}$, for any $p \in [a,b]$. By triangle inequality, $1 = \|f_p - f_q\| \leq \|f_p - s_p\| + \|f_q - s_p\|$, so $\|f_q-s_p\| \geq \frac{2}{3}$. This means all $s_p$ are different, i.e. $S$ is uncountable.

Comment: I'm having trouble seeing how to use this set of functions to show a contradiction.  Can you elaborate?

Comment: @OliverG It's a standard method for proving inseparability. If you can find an uncountable family of pairwise disjoint open sets, then any dense set must contain a point in each open set (which must be distinct, since pairwise disjoint), and hence each dense set must be uncountable.

Comment: @OliverG I've updated the answer.

Comment: So since each disjoint open ball has a point $s_p$ in $M$ and there's uncountably many $s_p$'s $M$ is uncountable and the assumption of countability is contradicted?